# Animating ViewPager to fullscreen on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have this vision in my head for my layout to act like most social media's profile pages. In my layout, I have a `ViewPager` that has a `listView` inside of it which is inflated in an adapter. How can I make this `ViewPager` container basically "push" the rest of my layout upwards? For example, this is part of my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Posts" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Animals" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_imageView">


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

All I want is for the `ViewPager` container to inflate to fullscreen upon scrolling upwards and then go back to normal on a down scroll, like Facebook, Instagram, Twitter do on their profile pages. Any help/ links will be greatly appreciated as I don't even know how to approach this problem.

Upon some more brainstorming, I have thought about animations to make the `ViewPager`'s height to `match_parent`. Are there any animations to change the height of the `ViewPager` along with a scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Its working. Use collapsing toolbar layout and make tab also scrollable.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

      <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#FAFAFB">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
        android:background="#ffffff">


      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
           <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivbackarrow"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/iconback"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivmap"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivfilter"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/iconmap"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivfilter"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/iconfilter"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                android:visibility="visible"

                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar_container">



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="185dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
      <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Results for"


                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:letterSpacing="0.05"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTitleText"/>
            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Egg plant"
                android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeText"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/verybiglargetextsize"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:textColor="#22262A"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:id="@+id/tabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:tabMode="fixed"
          android:layout_below="@+id/location"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
          android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="35dp" 
           app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#22262A"/>


      </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#FAFAFB"/>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```